# How to Calculate the Local Gradient of an Image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters, image-processing, image-segmentation

I know that the gradient function is supported by MATLAB, but the local gradient is not, so how do you calculate it?

> Local gradient is another texture descriptor, which is defined as:
>
> $$I_g=\sum_{z=-r}^{r} | \nabla I(x+\tau) |^2 $$

Comment: What do you mean by Local Gradient? Have you read it in an article you could link? It usually the classic gradient within a block.

Comment: Assume that given image is divided into blocks. Local gradient is gradient of these block. You can see some definition at http://ac.els-cdn.com/S1874102913600038/1-s2.0-S1874102913600038-main.pdf?_tid=77c7fac0-c857-11e3-a552-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1397976554_e0f181440db572cb8cd2b4828e0662c8

Comment: So, treat each block as it was an image and calculate the Gradient. Ot are you asking about the gradient of an image?

Comment: I ask about gradient of an image. I think that first we divide image into bocks. For each block, we calculate gradient of them. So, local gradient of given image is gradient of each block combination. We can implement it by Gradient(K*I), where K is one kernel to divide image into block, * is convolution. How about my scheme? Thank

Comment: I don't understand you. The gradient of an image or a block (Be more general a matrix) is well defined. For real life image the gradient is usually approximated by a filter, do you mean you want to show you that?

Comment: @Drazick: Let see the defination. I understand that It is gradient for each bock in the image. That mean first we divide it into block. And calculate gradient for them

Comment: pretty much out of ignorance, but the "gradient" $\nabla$ is a well-defined notion. i would like to ask, specifically, what is the quantity that the gradient operator is applied to.  and can you tell me what is $z$ in $$I_g=\sum_{z=-r}^{r} | \nabla I(x+\tau) |^2 $$ and whether $I_g(.)$ is a function of $x$ or $\tau$ or both?  i presume $I(x)$ is intensity along a single axis or is that presumption mistaken? $I_g$ looks like what i would call a *"mean-square gradient"*.  just outa ignorance and curiousity.

Comment: maybe it's s'pose to be $$I_g(x) = \frac{1}{2r+1} \sum_{z=-r}^{r} | \nabla I(x + z \tau) |^2 $$ and $z$ and $r$ are integers.  then it's the mean-squared of $I(x)$ in the area of the disk around $x$ with radius $r \tau$.  i'm just groping for a well-defined function.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Thank you for your comment. I read that paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187410291360003. Let see the defination at page 6 about local gradient. I think $z$ is gray level and I don't know what is $t$

Comment: @John, Could you review my answer? If it answers your question, could you mark it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, pay attention it is a calculation per pixel using a sata from a blog.
Basically summing the Gradient norm over a block / windows.

To calculate what you submitted above do the following:

1. Define the Finite Differences filters to approximate the gradient. Moreover build the "Win Summation" kernel which sums all elements within a window.

```
    mLocalSumFilter = ones(filterWinSize, filterWinSize);
    vGradXFilter = [-0.5, 0, 0.5];
    vGradYFilter = [-0.5; 0; 0.5];
```

2. Calculate the image gradients:

```
    mInputImageGradX = imfilter(mInputImage, vGradXFilter, 'replicate', 'same', 'corr');
    mInputImageGradY = imfilter(mInputImage, vGradYFilter, 'replicate', 'same', 'corr');
```

3. Calculate the norm of the gradient vector. Afterwards sum the norm of the gradient within the window.

```
    mInputImageGradNorm = sqrt((mInputImageGradX .^ 2) + (mInputImageGradY .^ 2));
    mInputImageGradNorm = imfilter(mInputImageGradNorm, mLocalSumFilter, 0, 'same', 'corr') ;
```

This is it.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have the Image processing toolbox the imgradient function should do what you want. It calculates the gradient magnitude (and direction) of each pixel using standard [Sobel gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator).

From the discussion it sounds like you may want to calculate the gradient some other way. If so I recommend either nlfilter for sliding window methods (i.e pixel by pixel) or blockproc for block processing. For these functions you will have to work out a suitable equation for the gradient yourself but this isn't hard.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error :
correct your source by converting `int8` to `double`

```
mLocalSumFilter = ones(filterWinSize, filterWinSize);
vGradXFilter = [-0.5, 0, 0.5];
vGradYFilter = [-0.5; 0; 0.5];
mInputImageGradX = imfilter(mInputImage, vGradXFilter, 'replicate', 'same', 'corr');
mInputImageGradY = imfilter(mInputImage, vGradYFilter, 'replicate', 'same', 'corr');

mInputImageGradX1=im2double(mInputImageGradX);
mInputImageGradY1=im2double(mInputImageGradY);
mInputImageGradNorm = sqrt((mInputImageGradX1 .^ 2.0) + (mInputImageGradY1 .^ 2.0));
mInputImageGradNorm = imfilter(mInputImageGradNorm, mLocalSumFilter, 0, 'same', 'corr') ;
imshow(mInputImageGradNorm);
```